# How to reference a color in a android xml resource that is defined in a lib?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, android-library

I have an android fragment `app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml` that references a color `bg_line` defined in `app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml`

`res/values/colors.xml` :

```
<resources> <color name="bg_line">#E7E7E7</color> ...
```

`fragment_main.xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout android:background="@color/bg_line" ... >...
```

I want to refactor my existing working code and move color `bg_line` into a different android library module
`mylib/src/main/res/values/colors.xml` that uses

`mylib/src/main/manifest.xml` :

```
<manifest package="de.k3b.mylib" ...>
```

My Question: how can i reference the color `bg_line` in `fragment_main.xml` if `bg_line` is defined in modul `:mylib`

in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource i found

```
> resource reference:
>    In Java: R.color.filename
>    In XML: @[package:]color/filename
```

- I found no example use for [package:]

i tried

- android:background="@android:color/bg_line"
- android:background="@app:color/bg_line"
- android:background="@mylib:color/bg_line"
- android:background="@de.k3b.mylib:color/bg_line"

I am using Android Studio (Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2)

Comment: the module that contains the layout fragment main.xml must implement (gradle) the module where the color definition is found. So it's just referencing the color as "before".

Comment: @Petruceli.L you mean i have to use `android:background="@color/bg_line"` as before and my android module lib `mylib` is not correctly referenced from the main app module `app` ? i will check it ....

Comment: @Petruceli.L after restarting android Studio and executing "rebuild all" all works as expected. Thanks. If you change your comment to an answer i can mark is as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the module that contains the layout fragment main.xml must implement (gradle) the module (:mylib) where the color definition is found. So it's just referencing the color as "before" (android:background="@color/bg_line").